# Lazy Load using WP_Query pagination

Tags: posts, wp-query, pagination

I've been thinking of using `WP_Query`'s pagination to make a custom lazy loading. is there a way to utilize the `WP_Query`'s pagination for a lazy load?

Say for example, I have to load 24 posts in the first load, and when the scroll reach bottom it will lazy load the next 24 post.

Is this possible?

Comment: What about AJAX? When you scroll down you just fetch 24 more posts.

Comment: @denis How to do that using AJAX? i really have no idea, i'm literally a newbie

Comment: @denis.stoyanov is correct. There are a couple of good ajax loaders. Do a google search for `ajax infinite scroll`.

Comment: @pieter, so basically, i can't use the wp_query pagination to make my own lazy load? :(

Comment: You are going to use `WP_Query`, but you will need to use that in conjunction with AJAX

Comment: You can use it, but your knowledge seems to not be enough (please, no offense) for us to write an answer that you understand to implement it as your own. That is why Pieter and others recommend to search for a ready-to-use solution. I recommend the one included in [JetPack plugin](https://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/). I hope you understand that you may start undestanding how `WP_Query` works, what Ajax is, how implement Ajax in WordPress, how to get paginated results with Ajax and `WP_Query`, and so on, so much things for an answer. You could start asking one thing after another.

Comment: I'm familiar with Ajax. So how can i configure it with wp_query?

Comment: If so, start adding a example of your Ajax implementation, working or not, that you are trying to integrate with `WP_Query` and explain where exactly do you have problems. Otherwise, your question "Is this possible?" has a simple answer: "Yes, it is". I hope you understand that you need to narrow down to specific problems to get a good answer. Do you know [how to implement Ajax within WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)? Do you know how to work with [paginated results in `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)?

Comment: @cybmeta, thank you. i will post a specific question for this if i encounter a problem

Comment: Forget the pagination when you want automatic infinite scroll or just load X amount of more posts on button press. You will have to use `offset` argument in `WP_Query()`. Just say the word and I can answer your question, it's easy and I have few minutes to help you out.

Comment: @N00b i just don't want to use infinite scroll. i want to use wp_query's pagination with ajax for special reason

Comment: _Say for example, I have to load 24 posts in the first load, and when the scroll reach bottom it will lazy load the next 24 post._ But this is what you wanted.. ?

Comment: Yeah i want that, @N00b. But i wanna utilize the wp_query pagination and ajax call. without importing any plugin such as infinite scroll. if it is possible that you could help me with that.

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-add-lazy-loading-to-wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this rough example. This requires a little bit of adaptation but as a whole, it does what you want - it loads X amount of next posts if user clicks a button which should be below already loaded posts.

If you want to automatically load more posts if user scrolls down, just replace click event with some other code that keeps an eye on scrolling. There's plenty of examples online.

- Keep an eye on `jQuery('some-html-element')-s`, make sure to rename these element names or change your own `HTML` to make them fit
- Total posts count: you can make it visible if you want users to see total posts count or use `CSS` `opacity` to hide it. It still needs to be somewhere in order to have a place to store the value

---

**This goes to your main .js:**

This function handles all the DOM manipulation and ajax. It can be called however you wish.

```
//ajaxLock is just a flag to prevent double clicks and spamming
var ajaxLock = false;

if( ! ajaxLock ) {

    function ajax_next_posts() {

        ajaxLock = true;

        //How many posts there's total
        var totalPosts = parseInt( jQuery( '#total-posts-count' ).text() );
        //How many have been loaded
        var postOffset = jQuery( '.single-post' ).length;
        //How many do you want to load in single patch
        var postsPerPage = 24;

        //Hide button if all posts are loaded
        if( totalPosts < postOffset + ( 1 * postsPerPage ) ) {

            jQuery( '#more-posts-button' ).fadeOut();
        }

        //Change that to your right site url unless you've already set global ajaxURL
        var ajaxURL = 'http://www.my-site.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

        //Parameters you want to pass to query
        var ajaxData = '&post_offset=' + postOffset + '&action=ajax_next_posts';

        //Ajax call itself
        jQuery.ajax({

            type: 'get',
            url:  ajaxURL,
            data: ajaxData,
            dataType: 'json',

            //Ajax call is successful
            success: function ( response ) {

                //Add new posts
                jQuery( '#posts-container' ).append( response[0] );
                //Update the count of total posts
                jQuery( '#total-posts-count' ).text( response[1] );

                ajaxLock = false;
            },

            //Ajax call is not successful, still remove lock in order to try again
            error: function () {

                ajaxLock = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**This goes to your main .js:**

This is an example how to call function above with button, this is better in my opinion, user can choose if he/she wants to see more..

```
//Load more posts button
jQuery( '#more-posts-button' ).click( function( e ) {

    e.preventDefault(); 

    ajax_next_posts(); 

});
```

---

**This goes to functions.php or create a mu-plugin:**

This is the function that "runs" in your server, ajax calls this, it does it's thing and sends results back.

```
//More posts - first for logged in users, other for not logged in
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_next_posts', 'ajax_next_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_next_posts', 'ajax_next_posts');

function ajax_next_posts() {

    //Build query
    $args = array(
        //All your query arguments
    );

    //Get offset
    if( ! empty( $_GET['post_offset'] ) ) {

        $offset = $_GET['post_offset'];
        $args['offset'] = $offset;

        //Also have to set posts_per_page, otherwise offset is ignored
        $args['posts_per_page'] = 24;
    }

    $count_results = '0';

    $query_results = new WP_Query( $args );

    //Results found
    if ( $query_results->have_posts() ) {

        $count_results = $query_results->found_posts;

        //Start "saving" results' HTML
        $results_html = '';
        ob_start();

        while ( $query_results->have_posts() ) { 

            $query_results->the_post();

            //Your single post HTML here
        }    

        //"Save" results' HTML as variable
        $results_html = ob_get_clean();  
    }

    //Build ajax response
    $response = array();

    //1. value is HTML of new posts and 2. is total count of posts
    array_push ( $response, $results_html, $count_results );
    echo json_encode( $response );

    //Always use die() in the end of ajax functions
    die();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @N00b, I will be trying your code and see if it works. :) I'll get back to you soon,

Comment: It works 100%, I tested it a little bit. You'll just have to adapt it correctly.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you @N00b, but i still have to modify it to fit my layout. By the way, How can Integrate the posts retrieved with my layout?

Comment: You mean how to add retrieved posts to your element? Take a look at `ajax success fuction`. `append()` adds new posts to your chosen element, just replace `#posts-container` with the id or class of your posts wrapper.

Comment: i'm quite confused. How can i get the post's image, title etc, when i append it directly?

Comment: Take a look at the last block of code which runs in server. I marked the right place with _Your single post HTML here_, this is the place where you'll add all the `HTML` you want a **single** post to have. It's in `while()` loop which means that it does it for each post.

Comment: Ow. I See :) Thanks so much, :) Sorry. I'm such an annoying newbie

Comment: Thanks @N00b... it was working. But i have to reinitialize my jquery. Other than that, the loading is great.

Comment: Im glad it's working. I also hope that you learned something in the process.

Comment: Yes, i did learn a lot. THANKS agaim @N00b. You're wonderful.

Comment: `var ajaxURL = window.location.protocol + '://' + window.location.hostname + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';`

Answer (score 0):

I've been using infinite scroll for this.

Here is what I have used in script.js

```
$(function(){
    var $container = $('#ms-container');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.ms-item',


      });
    });
//var templateUrl = object_name.templateUrl;
//var src =  "'"+templateUrl+"/images/loader.gif' ";

$container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '#navigation',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '#navigation a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.ms-item', 


      loading: {
          finishedMsg: $('<div class="finmsg">No More Posts.</div>'),
          msgText: '',
          img: '',
          speed: 0
        }
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );
});
```

I am using masonry, so you might need to tweak this. 
The overall container on the archive page is

```
<div id="ms-container">
```

Hence:

```
var $container = $('#ms-container');
```

My container for each individual post displayed on my archive page is:

```
<div class="ms-item col-sm-4">
```

Hence:

```
itemSelector : '.ms-item',
```

This is what I am using as the pagination at the bottom of the archive page:

```
      <div id ="navigation" class="pagination pull-left prevnext">
      <ul class="list-inline clearfix">
        <li class="text-left pull-left"><?php previous_posts_link( '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> Previous' );?></li>
        <li class="text-right pull-right"><?php next_posts_link( 'Next <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>'); ?></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
```

If I remember correctly this is where I got the info on how to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766515/imagesloaded-method-not-working-with-jquery-masonry-and-infinite-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer N00b. It worked really well. I tweaked it a little bit because the lock didn't work and I wanted to pull posts per page from the WordPress options page. I also reduced HTML markup by using the [jQuery .data() function](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

**Main JS**

```
(function($) {
    //Load more posts button
    $( '#more-posts-button' ).click( function( e ) {

        e.preventDefault(); 
        
        if( ! $("#more-posts-button").data("lock") ) {
            ajax_next_posts(); 
        }

    });

    function ajax_next_posts() {

        $("#more-posts-button").data("lock",true);
        
        //How many have been loaded
        var postOffset = $( '.single-post' ).length;


        //Change that to your right site url unless you've already set global ajaxURL
        var ajaxURL = '//' + window.location.hostname + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

        //Parameters you want to pass to query
        var ajaxData = '&post_offset=' + postOffset + '&action=ajax_next_posts';

        //Ajax call itself
        $.ajax({

            type: 'get',
            url:  ajaxURL,
            data: ajaxData,
            dataType: 'json',

            //Ajax call is successful
            success: function ( response ) {

                //Add new posts
                $( '.posts-container' ).append( response[0] );
                
                //Update the count of total posts
                $("#more-posts-button").data("count", response[1] );

                //How many posts there's total
                var totalPosts = $("#more-posts-button").data("count"); 

                //How many have been loaded
                var postOffset = $( '.single-post' ).length;

                //How many do you want to load in single patch
                var postsPerPage = response[2];

                //Hide button if all posts are loaded
                if( totalPosts < postOffset + ( 1 * postsPerPage ) ) {

                    $( '#more-posts-button' ).fadeOut();
                }

                $("#more-posts-button").data("lock",false);
            },

            //Ajax call is not successful, still remove lock in order to try again
            error: function () {

                $("#more-posts-button").data("lock",false);
            }
        });
    }
    
})( jQuery );
```

**Main HTML**

```
<div class="lazy-pagination"><a class="button" id="more-posts-button" href="#">Show more posts</a></div>
```

**functions.php**

```
//lazy load pagination
//More posts - first for logged in users, other for not logged in
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_next_posts', 'ajax_next_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_next_posts', 'ajax_next_posts');

function ajax_next_posts() {

    //Build query
    $args = array(
        //All your query arguments
    );

    //Get offset
    if( ! empty( $_GET['post_offset'] ) ) {

        $offset = $_GET['post_offset'];
        $args['offset'] = $offset;

        //Also have to set posts_per_page, otherwise offset is ignored
        $args['posts_per_page'] = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
    }

    $count_results = '0';

    $query_results = new WP_Query( $args );

    //Results found
    if ( $query_results->have_posts() ) {

        $count_results = $query_results->found_posts;

        //Start "saving" results' HTML
        $results_html = '';
        ob_start();

        while ( $query_results->have_posts() ) { 

            $query_results->the_post();

            //Your single post HTML here
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-blog', get_post_type() );
        }    

        //"Save" results' HTML as variable
        $results_html = ob_get_clean();  
    }

    //Build ajax response
    $response = array();

    //1. value is HTML of new posts and 2. is total count of posts
    array_push ( $response, $results_html, $count_results, $args['posts_per_page'] );
    echo json_encode( $response );

    //Always use die() in the end of ajax functions
    die();  
}
```